# How to map Set or List to array using jaxrs (resteasy) in Angular 5 app?

Tags: java, json, angular, jax-rs, resteasy

I have the following java code/Object:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Company implements java.io.Serializable {

    ...

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="trips")
    @XmlElement(name = "trip")
    private Set<Trip> trips = new HashSet<Trip>(0); 

    ... 
}
```

Here are the relevant jars files:
[image]

The response is json in the console:

```
"trips":{"trip":{"id":1,"name":"ABC"}}}}
```

As you can see the response doesn't include any brackets ("[]") which means
the resteasy doesn't convert it to array, This behaviour causes me a lot of issue in the angular app.
Is there a way to force the java/resteasy to convert to array so I can easily 
manipulate the array in the Angular app ?

What is the best practice to transform list to an Angular app ?
I believe that the json should be something like:

```
 "trips":{[{"id":1,"name":"ABC"},{"id":2,"name":"XYZ"}]}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by loading the trips separately and not by using inner array
inside the company object. This way I am able to get array which make my life easier 
inside the Angular app.